# JSON2APEX returning Null _id values

Tags: apex, json

I'm sure there has to be something small here that I'm missing. I have JSON array of values

```
[
    {
    _id : "55d78226726b611100aaf741",
    value1: 1,
    value2: 2
    }, 
    {_id: "55d66226726b611100bbf741",
     value1: 1, 
     value2: 2
    },
     etc....
    ]

Here is the casting that I'm doing when I make the api call. 

    System.debug(response.getBody());
            List<Json2Apex> equiMap = (List<Json2Apex>) JSON.deserialize(string.valueOf(response.getBody()), List<Json2Apex>.class);
            String value = (String)equiMap.get(1).x_id; 
            System.debug(value); 


I can see the value the _id value is present in the first `System.debug`, but in the second `System.debug` it shows as null. 

For simple lists like this, should JSON2Apex not be used? Thanks for the help.
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample response.getBody()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use reserved or illegal names with JSON.deserialize and a template class. You need to enable the use of "explicit parsing" in JSON2Apex, which generates a longer JSON parser in the form of a JSONParser script, which you then call as:

```
Json2Apex equiMap = Json2APex.parse(response.getBody().toString());
```

In other words, `JSON.deserialize(String, Class)` doesn't use any conventions; it can't automatically convert `_id` to `x_id`, so you need to use the parse method provided.

In your case, you may find it easier to instead generically deserialize your body:

```
List<Object> equiList = (List<Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody().toString());
for(Object equiItem: equiList) {
  Map<String, Object> equiMap = (Map<String, Object>)equiItem;
  System.debug(equiMap.get('_id'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I need to get a better understanding of casting into objects and when to use it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that using explicit parsing was not necessary. The solution above is still valid from @sfdcfox. This answer is another way of accomplishing it.

When Apex2JSON publishes, there is a `parse` method:

```
public static List<Apex2JSON> parse(String json) {
        System.JSONParser parser = System.JSON.createParser(json);
        return arrayOfApex2JSON(parser);
    }
```

You can use this method like this:

```
List<Apex2JSON> apexList = Apex2JSON.parse(response.getBody());

for (Apex2JSON a : apexList) {
    // Do stuff 
}
```

^^^^
The reason that this works is because the `parse` method in the `JSON2Apex class` returns a List of `JSON2Apex` objects. I had not thought about using the methods in the JSON2Apex generated class.

Again the casting option works as well up above from SFDCfox.